# Area of a Trapezoid

Tags: geometry

The bases of trapezoid $ABCD$ are $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$. Let $P$ be the intersection of diagonals $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$. If the areas of triangles $ABP$ and $CDP$ are 8 and 18, respectively, then find the area of trapezoid $ABCD$.

Hmm...  This problem is hard!  I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangles $CDP,ABP$ are similar, hence the ratio between their heights (relative to $CD$ and $AB$) is the square root of the ratio between their areas, i.e. $\frac{3}{2}$. Assuming that the distance of $P$ from $AB$ is $h_{AB}$ and $AB=x$ we have $h_{AB}x=16$. But if $h$ is the height of the trapezoid, $hx=\frac{5}{2}h_{AB}x = 40$. Since $h_{CD}=\frac{3}{2}h_{AB}$ and $y=CD=\frac{3}{2}x$, we have $h_{CD}y=36$ and $hy=\frac{5}{3}h_{CD}y=60$, so:
$$[ABCD]=\frac{hx+hy}{2}=\frac{40+60}{2}=\color{red}{50}.$$

Comment: Thanks, Jack!  Why didn't I see that the triangles are similar?